# AWS STS credentials access permission cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have 3 AWS accounts. Account A has a lambda (Lambda_Account_A), Account B has a role (Role_Account_B) and Account C has a s3 bucket (S3_Account_C). The resource in account C  is configured with a bucket policy that says - Role_Account_B can access this bucket.

If the lambda in Account A assumes Account B role (Role_Account_B) and generate STS credentials, will those credentials have access to Account C resource s3 bucket?

Account B and C has been configured to trust each other.

Account A lambda code:

```
try {
    AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn(assumeRole) //arn of the role in account B
            .withPolicy(policy) // policy contains "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
            .withDurationSeconds(3600)
            .withRoleSessionName(SESSION_NAME);

    // Assume the IAM role
    AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);

 
    final BasicSessionCredentials temporaryCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
            assumeResult.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId(),
            assumeResult.getCredentials().getSecretAccessKey(),
            assumeResult.getCredentials().getSessionToken());

    return temporaryCredentials;
} catch (AWSSecurityTokenServiceException e) {}
```

Bucket Policy in Account C:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account_No:role/Account_B_role”
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*”
        }
    ]
}
```

Role_B Permission policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's trust relationship has both the Account A and Account C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assume a role in another account its treated as if you're in that account.

As long as account B has the IAM permissions on this IAM role to access bucket in account C it will be able to perform those actions.

To prevent unauthorised access to certain permissions you can lockdown by using [external ids](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html) which are optionally specified when you assume a role. This allows you to lockdown specific permissions in the roles IAM policy by using conditions referencing the `sts:ExternalId`.

More information about external ids are available in [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-external-id-when-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources/).

Comment: In the trust relationship of Role_Account_B I have given access to Account C, and policy permission  as (s3*), but the STS generated can not access the Account C bucket.
I get this error:
`Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
Request ID: A51A3847E64F93D9; S3 Extended Request ID:`

Comment: Has the S3 bucket policy whitelisted the Account B role in its bucket policy? Have you got examples of your code?

Comment: Right I see the code there, although cannot see where these credentials are being used by S3 client. You appear to be specifying a policy but does the IAM role (configured in account B) itself have the permissions too? :)

Comment: You mean permission policy for Role_B. Yes. I have added that code as well.
The credentials are being used to create a S3 client in another part of the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218134/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-ta).